# how do I link to more items at bottom of content query web part?

Tags: content-query-web-part

I have two content query web parts each linked to a different announcements list.

I'm showing the most recent five announcments and would like to have a 'View all' link at the bottom.

I've found a way to hard code a link at the bottom, but I'd like for it to pull in the Title URL so I don't have to manually code the link for each CQWP that I might place on the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are they linked to one specific announcements lists the different CQWP, like CQWP1 is getting items from ListA, CQWP2 from ListB etc?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if the default CBQWP supports what you want out of the box, but if you're doing any other custom development in your solution you could provide a web part that inherits from `ContentByQueryWebPart`, and push through the `ListUrl` property into to the XSLT by overriding the `ModifyXsltArgumentList()` method. You can then customise the XSLT for ContentQueryMain.xsl (or, preferably, create a copy of it) to show the View All link. You'd then need to retrofit all current webparts where you want this functionality to be used.

Answer (score 0):

With javascript (jQuery for example) you can pretty easily grab the Title URL of a web part and after that modify the URL of the "View all" link at the footer.

Few months after this question I had to implement the same in my project, and I blogged the solution [here](http://blog.jussipalo.com/2012/05/sharepoint-append-link-to-bottom-of.html). Basically I use jQuery to find the correct CQWP, then find the list it links within CQWP and append a "Read more" type of link as the last item.